# Why don't memory cells of the adaptive immune system get activated immediately after being created?

Tags: immunology

Why don't [memory B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_B_cell) and [memory T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_T_cell) cells of the adaptive immune system get activated immediately after being created?

As this [video](https://youtu.be/xaz5ftvZCyI) explains they are created in the heat of the battle. Aren't the conditions for activation there? What mechanism prevents them from being activated right there and then?